# Using 'String' + Container as class name

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that container class in bootstrap is a class that that provide us template to hold 'something', and we just need to manipulate some of container aspect to use it, such as width and height.

So example

```
<div class="test container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

so the only benefit I know that we can access the first class using CSS with 2 ways, 1st using the .container class and the 2nd one is using .test

1. Is there any other benefit using 'string' + 'space' + container as a class?
2. Is it a bad idea to use 2 classes or more for 1 tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use 2 classes in one tag then their must be some use of it that why you applied and you can use it for giving stying or sometimes for defining function users add one more class.

Like above if you want to apply different css on 1st container as 2nd you can use it like this

```
.container.test{
   // css for first container only
}

.container{
   // css for both container
}
```

> There is no bad thing using two class in one tag you can use multiple classes in one tag totally depends on you use.